# DataGrid table are shown additional unnecessary empty row

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I use the following code and for example when the collection is field with data like with 2 item I see in the screen 2 rows with data and one more empty line at the end of the list.

How can I omit this last empty line? The collection are having just 2 entries. The collection items are having just 2 entries.

```
<DataGrid RowHeaderWidth="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <!--<DataGrid.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="LightBlue" />
        </DataGrid.Resources>-->
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="1" Width="*">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Column1, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Column2}" Header="2" Width="*" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Column3}" Header="3" Width="*" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Column4}" Header="4" Width="*" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Column5}" Header="5" Width="*" />
    </DataGrid.Columns> 
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try for [`CanUserAddRows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.canuseraddrows%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) set *false*, the registered default is true:

```
<DataGrid Name="MyDataGrid" 
          CanUserAddRows="False" ... />
```

Quote from [`MSDN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.canuseraddrows%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> When this property is set to *true* a blank row is displayed at the bottom of the DataGrid. A user can enter a new item into the blank row. Adding a new row adds an item to the ItemsSource.

Comment: Even if "CanUserAddRows" is false in the Properties window of the designer, if it's not explicitly set to False in XAML (CanUserAddRows="False") this won't work.